# How was this interior room photo lit? Window...Strobes...Both?

Tags: lighting, interior

I would like to understand how this scene is lit:

[image]

I can see that sunlight is coming from two big windows on the right. But is there some kind of studio equipment, like a soft box or something similar on the left side?

It is a nice light on the couch and dark corners of the room. I would really like to be able to get the same studio-like feel within my interior shots!

Comment: Plantleafs on the right side are in the shade. Seems to me, there was no secondary light.

Comment: @scottbb Will do when I get home :)

Comment: Studio like Feel? I would argue that the point or  the goal is not to have it feel like it’s staged or studio like.  One should not be aware of  artificial or staged  lighting in  architectural photography, it should just feel natural.

Answer (score 35):

**1. Some theory**

The first thing you need to understand is the inverse square law.

This is that the light intensity decays quadratically (1/x^2) when you are further apart from the light source.

<sub>I normally post this diagram flipped, but I am posting it like this to match your window.</sub>

[image]

If you put a softbox to the right side of the couch the light will decrease and the far side of the room will be darker.

[image]

On a big diffuse light, this is a bit more complex to calculate that on a spotlight, but it is also true.

You then, need either to work on a large studio and put some lights further away, or you can use a softbox, take multiple shots, and compose them in post, (doing the opposite of what I did to simulate the darkening).

A. Shoot with a correct exposure of the different zones

[image]

B. Compose

[image]

---

**2. It seems**

In the case of this image, I think it is actually natural light. Notice the reflection on the glass.

[image]

It probably has a good space in front of the window. If you have a building or a wall, this is actually the source light and the square law starts from that point.

[image]

---

**3. In some other cases**

On a normal studio shoot of an interior, you set up multiple light sources building the interior, you normally do not rely on just one source.

This *is not the case on this image*. But if you cannot take several shots, as my prior explanation; if you have a moving subject, some people, you can use additional lights. In this diagram, the lights are bounced into the walls and ceiling.

[image]

---

I want to point out two kinds of shadows the coach is producing.

The shadow on the left (orange) would be almost black if you only use one softbox. This is partially filled with light bouncing all over the place. In this case from the light of the other window (behind the camera)

[image]

If you are using studio lights, you need some of this fill light.

Comment: The word exponentially as you used it originally to describe the inverse-square law was correct. The exponents involved with the inverse-square law are ½ and 2. A quadratic equation involved in solving parabolic form such as trajectories and catenaries is not involved. I believe the advice given was incorrect and affects your answer negatively.

Comment: Some edition done. The diagram as such is more understandable flipped, but yeap, I made a new one to match the window.

Comment: @Stan Things that increase/decrease exponentially follow the form _a^x_, where _a_ is constant, and _x_ is the variable under consideration (time, in the case of things like population growth, for instance). Systems of the form _x_ ^2, or even _x^a_, are polynomial. In the case of inverse-square law, the polynomial order is 2, and we have a special term for that because it's so common: quadratic.

Comment: I posted the basic formula :o)

Comment: @Stan, Rafael, I'd love to continue this exponential/quadratic thing (preferably in chat, so as to not clutter this answer), but for the purposes of the answer, I suggest removing both words entirely. I suggest something along the lines of: "This is that the light intensity is reduced by the square of the distance (1/x²) from the light source."

Comment: Brilliant effort! However, "decays quadratically" is the way to go.

Comment: @Hueco That's what adding a bounty is for :)

Comment: @mattdm ahh, I always forget about that feature.

Comment: @Hueco question has to be open for a little longer first before it's available. I find it's pretty useless for actually attracting new answers, but it's great for rewarding existing ones.

Comment: I misread your first sentence as, "The first thing you need to understand is the universe" and was thinking, "What, _all_ of it? There's no hope."

Comment: "This is that the light intensity decays quadratically (1/x^2) when you are further apart from the light source." That's for a point source. For a softbox, it decays much more slowly for distances comparable to the width of the softbox.

Comment: That is why I commented "On a big diffuse light, this is a bit more complex to calculate that on a spotlight, but it is also true" It is not slow, it is a matter of proportion, area, direction, diffusion, etc. A softbox could be considered for example square 1 on my diagram. But the same applies even to a light source several thousand km, like a star. At some point, it becomes a point light.

Comment: The reflection on the glass on the table is also telling. Great analysis.

Answer (score 6):

I see no evidence of the use of a soft box in this shot. It is a bright room with a white reflecting painted wall/doorway opposite the large translucent light source/window and the photo is properly exposed. Welcome to photo.stack exchange. Tip: The reflections on the glass domes are a good indicator of the light source.

Edit: There is one window (source). It might appear as if there are two sources due to a sheer curtain half-covering the tall window. This creates a two-tone source where one half of the window has a half-to-three-quarter stop less light than the uncovered half of the window.